# What is the runtime Big O for this Bottom-Up memomization problem?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, dynamic

I'm currently solving a problem and came up with a solution. However, I need help calculating the runtime complexity for this problem.

Link to problem: https://algo.monster/problems/minimum_total_container_size

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.HashMap;

class Solution {
    public static int minContainerSize(List<Integer> boxSizes, int days) {
        // WRITE YOUR BRILLIANT CODE HERE
        HashMap<String, Integer> memo = new HashMap<>();
        return recursive(boxSizes, days, 0, memo);
    }
    
    public static int recursive(List<Integer> boxSizes, int days, int currentIndex, HashMap<String, Integer> memo) {
        int currentMax = 0;
        int minimumSize = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        
        String key = days + "|" + currentIndex;
        if(memo.containsKey(key)) return memo.get(key);
        
        if(days == 1) {
            for(int i = currentIndex; i < boxSizes.size(); i++) {
                currentMax = Math.max(currentMax, boxSizes.get(i));
            }
          task  return currentMax;
        }
        
        
        for(int i = currentIndex; i < boxSizes.size() - days + 1; i++) {
            currentMax = Math.max(boxSizes.get(i), currentMax);
            
            minimumSize = Math.min(recursive(boxSizes, days-1, i+1, memo) + currentMax, minimumSize);
        }
        memo.put(key, minimumSize);
        return memo.get(key);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> boxSizes = Arrays.stream(scanner.nextLine().split(" ")).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
        int days = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        scanner.close();
        int res = minContainerSize(boxSizes, days);
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Here is what I think the runtime is:

- this problem is a backtracking if we didn't add memo.
  -without memo, the runtime should be O(N ^ Days)
  where as N is length of boxSize and Days for days.
  -With memo,
  O(days * N) ???

Please correctly me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Without memoization it is exponential - at each method invocation you have `m` recursive calls (`m` - number of iterations in your `for` loop).